# Unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type"

Tags: php, postgresql

I am having trouble connecting to postgres (installed using hombrew version 9.4.4). I have previously been able to connect successfully. The only thing that I believe could have changed is I installed PHP 5.5.

I try to start the server:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres

LOG:  unrecognized configuration parameter "dynamic_shared_memory_type"
in file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf" line 130
FATAL:  configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf"
contains errors
```

My server logs return the same errors.
Here is the contents of the postgresql.conf file that is throwing the error:

```
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
                # supported by the operating system:
                #   posix
                #   sysv
                #   windows
                #   mmap
                # use none to disable dynamic shared memory
```

In attempts to troubleshoot, I commented out dynamic_shared_memory_type and got this error:

```
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.4, 
which is not compatible with this version 9.3.5.
```

However, running brew info postgres, I am told my version is 9.4.4.

Comment: and `postgres --version` what does it tell? (presumably 9.3.5).

Comment: `postgres --version` returns 9.3.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This command:

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

launches whatever `postgres` binary appears first in the `$PATH`.

In your case it happens to be postgres 9.3.5, presumably from a previous install and/or another installer. That version can't work with the postgresql.conf for 9.4.x because of the new `dynamic_shared_memory_type` parameter, but more importantly it can't work with a 9.4.x data directory anyway (data formats are not compatible across major versions).

The command `which postgres` would tell where it is on disk.

Normally the `postgres` binary  for brew should be located in `/usr/local/bin/postgres`. To avoid conflicting with another postgres, launch it with an absolute path instead of relative:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

and

```
 $ /usr/local/bin/postgres -v
```

to just check for the version number.

On Mac OS X, there are quite a few different installers, as listed in:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Installers/Mac_OS_X
with different disk layouts. It's not unusual on Mac to try different installers and end up with several postgres installs in parallel.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, didn't realize you had replied. Thanks for the thorough explanation. Launching with absolute path works perfectly.